# Android-Alert Dialog on location change through service

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

I want to pop up the alert dialog on location change through service. Here i have attached my manifest , Service and broadcastReciever codes.

In the console it is giving that .apk has been installed.

But i'm not getting any toast or alertdialog.

PLease correct me if i'm wrong.

Thanks.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.ser"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >

    <receiver android:name="com.ser.Myreceiver"
        android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">  
<intent-filter>  
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" /> 
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />  

</intent-filter>  
</receiver>


<service  android:enabled="true" 
    android:name="com.ser.RunService">
<intent-filter>  
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
    </service>    


</application>

</manifest>`
```

---

```
package com.ser;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.widget.Toast;



 public class RunService extends Service implements LocationListener{

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    System.out.println("**inside onCreate");
    super.onCreate();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    //Intent call = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL,Uri.parse("tel:+5555")); 
    //startActivity(call);
}
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("ALERT")
       .setTitle("Location")
       .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

           }
       });
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

 }
```

//Reciver

```
package com.ser;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
//import android.widget.Toast;
//import android.util.Log;

public class Myreceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("MYRECEIVER");
        //Toast.makeText(Myreceiver.this, "MyReciver",    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         Intent serviceLauncher = new Intent(context, RunService.class);
         context.startService(serviceLauncher);
         //Log.v("TEST", "Service loaded at start");

}

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

create an Activity and and register receiver in this activity and start service from this activity and use alert dialog in activity class

Comment: thank you :) but how to register the receiver in an activity? And i want to start the service on completion of boot and want to display the alert dialog even when the application is closed. How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

i have modified your code and its working fine with my testing mobile device (sony xperia)

---

### Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.ser"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
   <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true">        
    <service android:enabled="true" android:name=".MyService">  
        <intent-filter>  
            <action android:name="com.ser.MyService">  
            </action>  
        </intent-filter>
    </service>  

    <receiver android:enabled="true" android:name=".MyReceiver">  
        <intent-filter>  
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED">  
        </action></intent-filter>  
    </receiver> 

    </application>
```

### MyReceiver.java

```
package com.ser;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {     
        Toast.makeText(context, "MyReceiver Started..",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.v("Debug", "MyReceiver Started..");
        Intent myIntent=new Intent(context,MyService.class);        
        context.startService(myIntent);
    }
}
```

---

### MyService.java

```
package com.ser;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyService extends Service {

    private LocationManager locManager;
    private LocationListener locListener = new myLocationListener();

    private boolean gps_enabled = false;
    private boolean network_enabled = false;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {return null;}

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Service Started..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.v("Debug", "Service Started..");        

        locManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE); 
        try{
            gps_enabled = locManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        }
        catch(Exception ex){}
        try{
            network_enabled = locManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);           
        }
        catch(Exception ex){}

        if (gps_enabled) {
            locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locListener);
            Log.v("Debug", "gps_enabled..");
        }
        if (network_enabled) {
            locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locListener);
            Log.v("Debug", "network_enabled..");
        }   

        // We want this service to continue running until it is explicitly
        // stopped, so return sticky.
        return START_STICKY;
    }


    private class myLocationListener implements LocationListener{

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

            if(location!=null){
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"on location changed called..",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.v("Debug", "on location changed method called..");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}          

    }
}//service closed
```

---

still have any doubts for Receiver,Service and GPS classes let me know!!

or even your can check [Start Service from Broadcast Receiver](http://rdcworld-android.blogspot.in/2012/03/start-service-from-broadcast-receiver.html) and [Get Current Location](http://rdcworld-android.blogspot.in/2012/01/get-current-location-coordinates-city.html) links for details. hope it helps!!